# Is RNN initial state reset for subsequent mini-batches?

Tags: time-series, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Could someone please clarify whether the initial state of the RNN in TF is reset for subsequent mini-batches, or the last state of the previous mini-batch is used as mentioned in [Ilya Sutskever et al., ICLR 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2329)  ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn) or [`tf.nn.rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#rnn) operations allow to specify the initial state of the RNN using the `initial_state` parameter. If you don't specify this parameter, the hidden states will be initialized to zero vectors at the beginning of each training batch.

In TensorFlow, you can wrap tensors in `tf.Variable()` to keep their values in the graph between multiple session runs. Just make sure to mark them as non-trainable because the optimizers tune all trainable variables by default.

```py
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, max_length, frame_size))

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(256)
state = tf.Variable(cell.zero_states(batch_size, tf.float32), trainable=False)
output, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, initial_state=state)

with tf.control_dependencies([state.assign(new_state)]):
    output = tf.identity(output)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(output, {data: ...})
```

I haven't tested this code but it should give you a hint in the right direction. There is also a [`tf.nn.state_saving_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/static_state_saving_rnn) to which you can provide a state saver object, but I didn't use it yet.

Comment: what is the batch_size was variable, in this case, the `tf.Variable` created will throw an error cuz we need to specify the size of the variable.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to danijar's answer, here is the code for a LSTM, whose state is a tuple (`state_is_tuple=True`). It also supports multiple layers.

We define two functions - one for getting the state variables with an initial zero state and one function for returning an operation, which we can pass to `session.run` in order to update the state variables with the LSTM's last hidden state.

```py
def get_state_variables(batch_size, cell):
    # For each layer, get the initial state and make a variable out of it
    # to enable updating its value.
    state_variables = []
    for state_c, state_h in cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32):
        state_variables.append(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(
            tf.Variable(state_c, trainable=False),
            tf.Variable(state_h, trainable=False)))
    # Return as a tuple, so that it can be fed to dynamic_rnn as an initial state
    return tuple(state_variables)


def get_state_update_op(state_variables, new_states):
    # Add an operation to update the train states with the last state tensors
    update_ops = []
    for state_variable, new_state in zip(state_variables, new_states):
        # Assign the new state to the state variables on this layer
        update_ops.extend([state_variable[0].assign(new_state[0]),
                           state_variable[1].assign(new_state[1])])
    # Return a tuple in order to combine all update_ops into a single operation.
    # The tuple's actual value should not be used.
    return tf.tuple(update_ops)
```

Similar to danijar's answer, we can use that to update the LSTM's state after each batch:

```py
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, max_length, frame_size))
cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(256) for _ in range(num_layers)]
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)

# For each layer, get the initial state. states will be a tuple of LSTMStateTuples.
states = get_state_variables(batch_size, cell)

# Unroll the LSTM
outputs, new_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, initial_state=states)

# Add an operation to update the train states with the last state tensors.
update_op = get_state_update_op(states, new_states)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run([outputs, update_op], {data: ...})
```

The main difference is that `state_is_tuple=True` makes the LSTM's state a LSTMStateTuple containing two variables (cell state and hidden state) instead of just a single variable. Using multiple layers then makes the LSTM's state a tuple of LSTMStateTuples - one per layer.

Comment: Note the way you do it you create num_layers _identical_ cells which is not what you want to do probably

Comment: What to do when the batch_size is determined during run time?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D thanks for the hint, I updated the code.

Comment: @I.A you can give get_state_variables the maximum batch_size you expect to create the state variables and ignore the unused state variables

Comment: I am getting an error TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.