# How to set the History input of a RNN/LSTM cell to Zero?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow

In order to do "Inference" with a trained RNN/LSTM model for sentences one by one. I think I need to set the **History input parameter** of a RNN/LSTM cell to Zero at the beginning of each sentence.

So how can it be done in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441589/tensorflow-rnn-initial-state) I believe that the state is set back to whatever state you pass in with the `initial_state` argument to `tf.nn.rnn` (or the other RNN creation functions).

Comment: First, thanks. However, I think I don't fully understand the `initial_state`. I'm not sure this set whether or not both effect the parameter of History and the parameter of current Input.

Comment: If you look at the code here, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py, it doesn't appear that the LSTMCells have a history parameter.

Comment: If you mean the `state` argument to when they are called, that is handled by the `rnn` function (or again one of the related functions).

Comment: So...This means that each time I want to Inference a sentence, the only thing I should do is to set the `initial_state`, which means I don't need to reload the model parameter from the checkpoint(only reload for the first time), is it right?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you don't even need to do that. If you set the `initial_state` argument to be constant with value zero, you should just be able to have the session run your example.

Comment: Just sentence by sentence is OK? Will context of previous sentence affect current one?

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I did a tiny experiment. However, I don't why it seems not logical to me...

Comment: They probably made that the default since it's most convenient and training time. You can save the state by replacing the initial state with a variable.